# stuck in Clojure recursion

Tags: recursion, clojure

I am trying to write a recursive function in `clojure`. The function returns the greatest number of given collection. If the collection is emty then it should return `nil`.
My code is:

```
(defn gum [coll]
 (if (empty? coll)
  0 
  (max (first coll)
   (gum (rest coll)))))
```

Expected result:

```
(gum [1 2 98 -3]) => 98
(gum [1 9]) => 9
(gum []) => nil
```

But I am getting:

```
(gum [1 2 98 -3]) => 98
(gum [1 9]) => 9
(gum []) => 0 (not desired result - should be `nil`)
```

This is because I have kept the value of `(empty? coll)` as `0`. If I keep it as `nil` then `(gum [1 2 98 -3])` won't work. Any suggestion as how to bring the value of `(gum [])` as `nil` and `(gum [1 2 98 -3])` as `98` at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

```
(defn gum [[head & tail]]
  (if (empty? tail)
      head
      (max head (gum tail))))
```

I'm using destructuring here instead of `first` and `rest`, but it's the same as:

```
(defn gum [coll]
  (let [head (first coll)
        tail (rest coll)]
    (if (empty? tail)
        head
        (max head (gum tail)))))
```

But you should try to avoid constructions like `(max head (gum tail))`, because Clojure can't optimize it. Try using tail recursion with [recur](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/recur) whenever possible:

```
(defn gum [[head & tail]]
  (if (empty? tail)
      head
      (recur (cons (max head (first tail))
                   (rest tail)))))
```

`recur` allows Clojure to use [Tail Call Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) to convert your recursive call into an iterative one, allowing it to be run in a constant stack space. It not only makes your code faster, but also protects it from stack overflow.

You should also consider using Higher Order Functions instead of recursion (as [SaltyEgg suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562398/stuck-in-clojure-recursion#19562570)):

```
(defn gum [coll]
  (if-let [s (seq coll)]
    (reduce max s)))
```

In most cases they provide an easier solution. And they are pretty good optimized.

Comment: This isn't TCO friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(defn gum [coll]
 (if (empty? coll)
  nil 
  (reduce max coll)))
```

Comment: @user227666 If you want recursion, add a condition `(= 1 (count coll))` when returns the only element.

Comment: I am not able to get you, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to redefine the [`max`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max) function ?

Now if you are looking to understand how the max function works, it ususally a good idea to look at the source `(source max)` in a repl :

```
(defn max
  "Returns the greatest of the nums."
  {:added "1.0"
   :inline-arities >1?
   :inline (nary-inline 'max)}
  ([x] x)
  ([x y] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (max x y)))
  ([x y & more]
   (reduce1 max (max x y) more)))
```

Note that `(apply max [])` will throw an exception rather than returning `nil` : `ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core/max  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)`

Edit :
That's why the approach to check first if we want to apply `max` and then (maybe) apply, as suggested by other answers :

```
(defn gum [coll]
  (if-let [s (seq coll)]
    (reduce max s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the same function inside because Clojure does not have tail recursion optimization (TRO). Use `(recur arg1 arg2 etc)` to iterate on the next step. And don't forget to add an `if` statement to leave the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, using same logic as you have described, returning singleton elements instead of zero:

```
(defn gum [coll]
  (if (or (empty? coll) 
          (singleton? coll))
    (first coll)
    (max (first coll) (gum (rest coll)))))
```

with:

```
(defn singleton? [coll]
  (if (first coll) (empty? (rest coll)) false))
```